# Parse JSON String which contains an array with InputReader?

Tags: json, swift, swift2, nsjsonserialization, nsinputstream

I have a problem with JSON. I searched through Internet, but didn't found any solution that worked for me.

For better working I saved the answer (JSON) of the server in a *.json file.
The JSON is looking like this (short version):

> {"data":"[{\"id\":38,\"name\":\"Anton\"},{\"id\":160,\"name\":\"Christopher Eth\"}]"}

I want to parse the Array, which is sent in "data" as a String. I am trying to get the String out of "data" and pass the String again in the NSJSONSerialization.

Is that the right way?

```
guard let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("names", ofType: "json") else {
        print("Error finding File")
        return
    }

    do {
        let data:NSData? = NSData(contentsOfFile: path)

        if let jsonResult =
            try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                let result = jsonResult["data"]
                if(result == nil){
                    print("error")
                }else{
                    //How can I convert the result! to an Stream to pass it to the JSONSerialization???
                    let stream = NSInputStream(/*result!*/)
                    let resultArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithStream(stream: stream, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSArray{
                    //Do something with array
                }

    }catch let error as NSError{
        print("Error: \(error)")
        return
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`NSStream` is not needed, just convert the JSON string into `NSData` and call `JSONObjectWithData` a second time.

```
guard let url = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("names", withExtension: "json"), jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url) else {
  print("Error finding File")
  return
}
do {
  let names = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
  if let jsonResult = names["data"] {
    let nameData = jsonResult.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    let resultArray = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(nameData, options: .MutableContainers) as! [[String:AnyObject]]
    for item in resultArray {
      print(item["name"]!, item["id"]!)
    }
  } else {
    print("error")
  }
} catch let  error as NSError {
  print(error)
}
```